# Typemock: How to run unit tests on data transformations?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, typemock

I'm trying to add unit tests to an existing system, which uses **AutoMapper** extensively.

The class ***Search*** uses the ***DB*** class. The data type is transformed when exchanged using **Automapper**.

`DB class: Returns DBSearchResult[]`

`Search class: Returns SearchResult` (holds List of `SearchResult` and an integer, let's say 1000)

`DBSearchResult mock holds: DBSearchResult[2]`

Note that `DBSearchResult` is converted using AutoMapper to SearchResult.

My intention is to check whether the `Search` class `SearchResult` will contain the right values (2 and 1000), but this means **Automapper** kicks in.

How do I deal with **Automapper**'s transformation of the datatypes without mocking it and basically testing a mock, and not the real implementation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After consulting with TypeMock, the conclusion is: Mock everything but the data transformation.

This way you test the actual work of AutoMapper, but avoid the other dependencies.

AutoMapper is initialized like the application would init it.